# Read Excel file from Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have to read an excel file stored in Sharepoint using Python, using below Code.
I am getting the below error:

*An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.*

When I login into Sharepoint, it's 2-step authentication:

1st: Username & Password

2nd: Approving Login request in Microsoft Authenticator app in my mobile.

How to incorporate the 2-step authentication in the Get request?

```
url = 'https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXX'
path = '/Shared%20Documents/XXX.xlsx'
username = 'my-username'
password = 'my-password'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
file = "https://content.potatocompany.com/workspaces/PotatoTeam/Shared Documents/XYZ errors/XYZ Errors_Confirm.xlsx"
        
username = 'myUsername'
password = 'myPassword'
        
resp=requests.get(file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
output = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```